# Powerbuilder 32 bit app Windows 7 ODBC ASA 8.0

Tags: powerbuilder, sybase-asa, powerbuilder-build-deploy

I have a 32 Bit Powerbuilder 9.0 app using ASA 8.0 and the ODBC connection, everything works fine under windows XP, but under windows 7 it fails, I have tried various combinations of registry settings to try and get this to work, but to no avail, I have read many articles about the different odbc32.exe in the different windows\system or wow64 folders but I never seem to hit the nail on the head properly. I am using Inno to build the Installation files. I am getting a bit desperate about this to the point of using a different db

Thanks

Colin

Comment: Since you are using ODBC, how are you creating the ODBC DSN on the client machine?  The ODBC setup in the registry is different in Win7. I guess I'd like to know first; can you connect to the DB using your ODBC DSN on Win7 using another tool?  If yes, then we have probably ruled out a DSN problem.

Comment: Thanks for your prompts response, to start to answer your questions, on my Windows XP Machine, the DSN is set in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.ini on the Windows & Machine it is under the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.ini\ODBC Data Sources and reads My app with a value of 'Adaptive Server Anywhere 8.0.

Comment: When the app fails it displays the 'Select Data Source' Box with the file tab File 'Data Sources' ( which is empty )

Comment: Based on what you are saying it sounds like the ODBC DSN isn't set up properly.  Try going into the ODBC Administrator and edit the ODBC DSN, then click on "Test Connection". You will probably get the same result. Fix the DSN until it passes the "Test Connection" then it should work fine in PB.  If you need to know the registry keys, you can look at the settings after you get it working properly, but setting ODBC DSN's via install scripts is no fun unless you have a nice tool like Install Shield.  Go to the preview tab and copy the connection parameters to use in your app.

Answer (score 1):

If your OS is a Win7 64b, and if the datasource is set by a 32b application, the settings are probably mapped into the `Wow6432Node` branch of the `HKLM\software` registry. `Wow64` stands for *Windows on Windows64*. The full path will be `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI\`.

Therefore, the ODBC32 is not directly visible by the 64b Data Sources administrative tool. Instead you must search for `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`.

The 32b data sources should still be accessible to a 32b application.